# Windows XP: no CSS for IE, Firefox or .CHMs

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, firefox, css, windows

I'm having a strange problem with the Windows XP machine of one of our developers after having installed .NET 3.5 SP1 (at least, the behaviour wasn't apparent before this point).

After installation, neither Firefox nor IE would display any CSS, but Chrome *would*. Using Firebug under FF, the CSS was being downloaded & read by the browser, just not applied. Any manual CSS changes made through Firebug wouldn't appear either.

Now I've noticed that the problem occurs with .CHM files too, which makes sense given its reliance on the same underlying libs as IE. This seems to imply that Firefox is using one or more of the same components that IE does for handling CSS (but that Chrome isn't)?

I've tried:

- removing & reinstalling Firefox
- installing IE8
- removing & reinstalling the .NET SP
  update
- reverting to an earlier system
  restore point

None of which has made any difference whatsoever.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: .NET is installed on all machines, not only workplace. I have seeing similar errors out of corporate environment, never within. But I respect your opinion. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried backing up your profile, deleting it, and letting it be recreated? The culprit might be there.

Comment: Do you mean Windows profile?

Comment: @Alex, yes, Windows' user profile.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably caused by the "High Contrast" setting in Windows' Accessibility Options. Turning the "High Contrast" feature off, should resolve the issue.